# WebStorm debugging create-react-native-app

Tags: webstorm, react-native, create-react-native-app

What should I set in `Run Debug Configuration` in WebStorm to debug a app created by **[create-react-native-app](https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app)**?

[image]

I'm at a loss on how to debug since it doesn't use `~/.node_modules/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli` but a custom module called `react-native-scripts` to start the compiling:

package.json:

```
 "main": "./node_modules/react-native-scripts/build/bin/crna-entry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native-scripts start",
    "eject": "react-native-scripts eject",
    "android": "react-native-scripts android",
    "ios": "react-native-scripts ios",
    "test": "node node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js --watch",
    "menu": "adb shell input keyevent 82"
  },
```

Comment: https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2016/12/developing-mobile-apps-with-react-native-in-webstorm/ -- is it still actual? This blog post has been edited today/yesterday .. so it should...

Comment: @LazyOne I can't find anything related to CRNA in the article, but I've left a comment on it. The main issue is I need to figure out how to start the CRNA's own react native package for webstorm to debug.

Comment: @RedGiant Debugging of create-react-native-app applications requires providing Expo support. This is not in out nearest plans unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

You have to use Webstorm/Intellij 2018.1 (through EAP at the moment)

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-26951
https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2018/02/webstorm-2018-1-eap-181-3263/#debugging-expo

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can do this, at least not in an easy way, and why would you wan't to do it anyway?

React Native ships with great debugging capabilities "out of the box" via Chrome Developer Tools.
Here you can debug code, both running on emulators, and even better on a real device.
See here for details: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging.html